# Can the parent process find out the PID of a daemon process created via a double fork

Tags: python, fork

I have some python code that forks twice to create a daemon. I know code like this is not at all uncommon so I was surprised I couldn't find people mentioning how you get the PID of your grandchild process here. I am willing to explore all options. Even if necessary using the filesystem. I just want to do it in the most correct/safe way possible.

```
try: 
    child1Pid = os.fork() 
    if child1Pid > 0:
        # parent process, return and keep running
        return

os.setsid()

# do second fork (first parent has already exited)
try: 
    child2Pid = os.fork() 
    if child2Pid > 0:
        # exit from second parent
        sys.exit(0)
```

The sticker here is that the parent process has already exited by the time child2Pid is known and there would be no value to forking on the parent process twice.

I am fine with using locks/waits/synchronization methods/whatever is needed. I am just trying to be cautious here as I want to make sure I do something safe.